# IdentityServer Hybrid Flow - Access Token is null after user successful login

Tags: asp.net, identityserver3, openid-connect, identityserver4

I'm having problems in retrieving access token of an authenticated user. below is my configuration

ASP.NET MVC 5 Client:

- OpenIdConnect
- IdentityServer3 libraries
- ResponseType = "code id_token"

ASP.NET Core Identity Server:

- IdentityServer4 libraries
- Client Config: AllowedGrantTypes =
  GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

I'm trying to get the access token in my client using this:

```
AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
{
    // use the code to get the access and refresh token
    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(TokenEndpoint, "clientid", "secret");
    var response = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, n.RedirectUri);      

},
```

I used this reference for above implementation - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2457

but the properties in the `response` has null values. I need the access token so that the user logged in the client can access the api. Below is another way that i'm trying to retrieve the access token:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CallApiUsingUserAccessToken()
{
    var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
    var accessToken = user.FindFirst("access_token").Value;

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
    var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:6001/api/values");

    ViewBag.Json = JArray.Parse(content).ToString();
    return View("json");
}
```

however, `user.FindFirst("access_token").Value;` is null. I'm thinking of migrating my MVC client to Core because I've tried the IdentityServer4 version in an asp.net core but that seems to be a big migration to my part. Thank you.

**[updated]**

It never occured to me that the endpoints in the IdentityServer3 differs from IDS4. I did have to change `var tokenClient = new TokenClient(TokenEndpoint, "client", "secret");` to `var tokenClient = new TokenClient("http://localhost:9000/connect/token", "client", "secret")` since TokenEndpoint in IDS3 is http://localhost:9000/core/connect/token which the endpoint "core" does not exist in IDS4. I'm able to get the access token in this line `var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, n.RedirectUri);` but after authorization, i'm still getting nullreference exception to this `var accessToken = user.FindFirst("access_token").Value;` line of code.

Comment: What's your `scope` value?

Comment: i believe it is not related to the scope value since it is working in my MVC client (Core) with IDS4 implemented. but here it is: IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,                        "myapi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to these posts, https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2457 & https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2015#issuecomment-172623173, it is a good practice to not include the access token in the claims. Hence, I followed his example, https://github.com/Mich-b/IdentityServerTMLClient/blob/master/IdentityServerTMLClient/Startup.cs, in which the access token is added in the Http Session storage.

Comment: The last link is broken ;(

Answer (score 1):

Given the IdentityServer 4 documentation on

- [Switching to Hybrid Flow and adding API Access back](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html#switching-to-hybrid-flow-and-adding-api-access-back)

and an example client from [IdentityServer3.Samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples)

- [MVC OWIN Client (Hybrid)](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/MVC%20OWIN%20Client%20(Hybrid))

you should be able to setup a working environment.

To support debugging you should always do proper response handling as shown in example below and [copied from example client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/2530a305b74ef3640e70b137734820f29bc7f34e/source/Clients/MVC%20OWIN%20Client%20(Hybrid)/Startup.cs#L57-L63). Add any response errors to your question.

```
 Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                        {
                            // use the code to get the access and refresh token
                            var tokenClient = new TokenClient(
                                Constants.TokenEndpoint,
                                "mvc.owin.hybrid",
                                "secret");

                            var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                                n.Code, n.RedirectUri);

                            if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                            {
                                throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                            }
```

Finally I recommend to add code for all important parts of an IdentityServer3/4 based setup - because the truth is usually burried in the details.

Comment: thanks for this, sascha. i'll try and implement. Will get back asap.

Comment: thanks @Sascha. i added the remaining code in AuthorizationCodeReceived in the sample. I got confused when i followed this post (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2457) removed those codes the manually adds the access token in the claims. I was searching for a way to not see the access token via claims just like in IDS4 (ASP.NET CORE) implementation wherein it can be retrieved in `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync` but this is not available in IDS3 (ASP.NET MVC 5)